# Launch four panel instance from batch script

Tags: conemu

How to you launch an instance of ConEmu from a batch script that has the following:

- 4 panels (2x2)
- no previous setup so that the batch script and any configuration both checked into source control
- each panel executes a console application from 4 different directories such as:

  - c:\App1\App1.exe
  - c:\App2\App2.exe
  - c:\App3\App3.exe
  - c:\App4\App4.exe

The use case I'm after is:

- a developer installs ConEmu
- either clicks the batch script

or

- calls it from whatever prompt they have available to them

Afterwards ConEmu would be running the 4 console applications in a way that they can see the output from all of them and not have to tab between views to see what each one is doing.  I was able to get this working via a manual setup but just can't seem to parse the docs enough to see how to do this cleanly from a non-ConEmu commandline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From batch file, without pre-config, obligatory? `/cmlist` allows to do that (I'm using same for debug purposes from Visual Studio). Use last alphas of course

```
ConEmu /cmdlist  c:\App1\App1.exe -cur_console:n ^|^|^| c:\App2\App2.exe -cur_console:s1TVn ^|^|^|  c:\App3\App3.exe -cur_console:s1THn ^|^|^|  c:\App4\App4.exe -cur_console:s2THn
```

The delimiter between "tabs" is `|||` in fact, but you need to escape `|` symbol in cmd-files.